# Stuck with regex expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to test a string like this one in javascript:

```
var str = "eleme_eus = \'Generikoa_Erlijioa\' or eleme_eus like \'Eliza_igles_a\' or eleme_eus like \'Parroki_a\' or eleme_eus like \'Erm_ita\' or eleme_eus like \'Komen_tua\' or eleme_eus like \'Santutegia\'";
```

I've been trying to create a regex to do so, but I cannot pass the \' part.

For now, I have (working):

```
var regex = /\w\s(=|like)\s/;
```

After that, I've tried scaping the backslash, the quotation mark... always false.

I just need to get to the "or/and" part, after that it repeats itself.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

With both websites (thx), I've come to this expression:

[image]

```
\w+[-\w]*\s(=|like)\s\\\'\w+\\\'(\s(and|or)\s\w+[-\w]*\s(=|like)\s\\\'\w+\\\')*
```

but if I test it in the console (Chrome)...

[image]

```
regex.test("field-name like \'word\' or field-name like \'word_word\'");
```

Comment: I suggest using tools [like this](http://regexr.com/) to test our regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
var re = /\w+[-\w]*\s(?:=|like)\s'\w+'(?:\s(?:and|or)\s\w+[-\w]*\s(?:=|like)\s'\w+')*/g;
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QEPuf6/1)

```
var str = "field-name like 'word' or field-name like 'word_word'";
re.test(str);
//=> true

str = "eleme_eus = \'Generikoa_Erlijioa\' or eleme_eus like \'Eliza_igles_a\' or eleme_eus like \'Parroki_a\' or eleme_eus like \'Erm_ita\' or eleme_eus like \'Komen_tua\' or eleme_eus like \'Santutegia\'";
"eleme_eus = 'Generikoa_Erlijioa' or eleme_eus like 'Eliza_igles_a' or eleme_eus like 'Parroki_a' or eleme_eus like 'Erm_ita' or eleme_eus like 'Komen_tua' or eleme_eus like 'Santutegia'"    
re.test(str);
//=> true
```

Your input doesn't have literal backslashes because `\'` will be interpreted as just single `'`.

Comment: In the end, the problem was that I was testing with a string without escaped backslashes. My original string had the backslashes already escaped. I marked this as correct because my question is answered by this, but I wrote it wrong xDDD Too many hours, sorry guys.

Answer (score 3):

Well here you need to escape both the `/` and the `'`, like this:

```
var regex = /\w\s(=|like)\s\\\'\w+\\\'/;
```

You can see it's correct in [**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vQFv9y/1/).

Comment: I see it working in that site and I already tested that. But regext.test("...") returns always false :S

Comment: @SergioTx Can you please update you question with you whole code?

Comment: OK, added some more info.